# Multiple the amount of sold products with the price of the product

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables look like this:

**tblartikel(artikelid primary key, price)**

**tblbestallning(artikelid, amount)**

I saw someone do this:
**select artikelid, sum(amount) as AmountSold from tblbestallning group by artikelID**

this correctly showed the artikelid's and thee amount it has ever been bought

how do i multiply the times it has been bought with the price?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the relationship between the two tables but assuming there is only one price per artikel, this would be a good starting point

```
SELECT tblbestallning.artikelid,
SUM(amount) as AmountSold,
SUM(amount*price) AS 'TotalSold'
FROM tblbestallning
JOIN tblartikel ON tblartikel.artikelid = tblbestallning.artikelid
GROUP by tblbestallning.artikelid
```